# Error not handled in the catch method of async/await function when called?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch

Trying to grasp the concept of async code. Why isnt the error message passed to the chained catch method when the function is invoked?

Would also appreciate any feedback on the how I structured the error handling. After what I read you should always throw error and never return them, but can it make sense in a situation like this? Trying to future-proof it by using the concept of DRY, so I can implement this with subtract, multiply and divide (not dividing by zero too).

```
const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const input = (num1, num2) => {
  if (!Number.isInteger(num1) || !Number.isInteger(num2)) {
    return new Error('Provide whole numbers only');
  }
  return null;
};

const asyncAdder = async (arg1, arg2) => {
  try {
    await timer(500);
    const validate = input(arg1, arg2);
    if(validate){
      throw validate;
    }
    return number1 + number2;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

asyncAdder(1,2.1).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I'm trying to go back and fourth between promises and async/await to understand the relationship, so these two are supposed to represent each other. Because when using promises, it will be caught in the catch method. Thanks for any feedback.

```
const promiseAdder = (arg1, arg2) => {
  const validate = input(arg1, arg2);
  return timer(500).then(() => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    if (validate) {
      rej(validate);
    } else {
      res(arg1 + arg2);
    }
  }));
};
```

Comment: Why not just use `.catch(console.log)` instead of a pointless arrow function? Also, I would recommend using `console.error` for errors.

Comment: It's unclear why you expect the `.catch()` callback to be executed. The error you `throw` in the `asyncAdder` body is already caught be `asyncAdder`'s own `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Because when making test files I want to end up in the test's catch method to see if I'm getting the expected result